# Use AdobeMobileLibrary (for iOS) with cocoapods?

Tags: ios, static-libraries, cocoapods, adobe-analytics

We are going to use Omniture-Tracking for iOS, which is part of AdobeMobileLibrary.
AdobeAdobeMobileLibrary is not available via cocoapods-repo (only an older version of Omniture), but as a static-library, that you can download from the Adobe Website.

I wonder if it is possible to maintain this static-library with cocoapods?

I've created a podspec-file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name           = 'AdobeMobileLibrary'
  s.version        = '4.0.2'
  s.license        = 'Commercial'
  s.summary        = 'Adobe Omniture SiteCatalyst analytics library for iOS.'
  s.homepage       = 'https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/content_page/mobile/c-measuring-mobile-applications'
  s.author         = { 'Adobe Omniture SiteCatalyst' => 'http://www.adobe.com/solutions/digital-marketing.html' }
  s.source_files   = 'AdobeMobileLibrary/*.{json,h}'
  s.ios.vendored_library = 'AdobeMobileLibrary/AdobeMobileLibrary.a'
  s.library        = 'AdobeMobileLibrary'
  s.xcconfig       = { 'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"$(PODS_ROOT)/AdobeMobileLibrary"' }
end
```

In my podfile I reference the podspec-file like s this:

```
pod 'AdobeMobileLibrary', :path => 'AdobeMobileLibrary.podspec'
```

In the Pods-project I can see all the files (AdobeMobileLibrary.a, ADBMobile.h, ADBMobileConfig.json)

see 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnmp1.png

However I cannot build the project and receive this error message:

```
ld: library not found for -lAdobeMobileLibrary
```

Does anyone have a clue, what's the problem here?

Is there a different solution to use AdobeMobileLibrary with cocoapods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is due to cocoapods expecting the library to have a *lib* prefix, i.e. *libAdobeMobileLibrary.a* in this case.  The easiest way to resolve this issue is to create a symbolic link to the library:

```
ln -s AdobeMobileLibrary.a libAdobeMobileLibrary.a
```

It's also worth noting that with the Adobe Mobile SDK, the .json file should be included as a resource not as source.  Also you'll want to add references to both the SystemConfiguration framework as well as libSqlite3.0.dylib.  Here's your pod spec modified accordingly:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s| 
  s.name           = 'AdobeMobileLibrary'
  s.version        = '4.0.2'
  s.license        = 'Commercial'
  s.summary        = 'Adobe Omniture SiteCatalyst analytics library for iOS.'
  s.homepage       = 'https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/content_page/mobile/c-measuring-   mobile-applications'
  s.author         = { 'Adobe Omniture SiteCatalyst' => 'http://www.adobe.com/solutions/digital-marketing.html' }
  s.source_files   = 'AdobeMobileLibrary/*.h'
  s.resource       = 'AdobeMobileLibrary/ADBMobileConfig.json'
  s.framework      = 'SystemConfiguration'
  s.ios.vendored_library = 'AdobeMobileLibrary/AdobeMobileLibrary.a'
  s.libraries      = 'sqlite3.0','AdobeMobileLibrary'
  s.xcconfig       = { 'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"$(PODS_ROOT)/AdobeMobileLibrary"' }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution!

To achieve the issue with the lib-prefix, I've added a Run Script to Build Phases in Xcode, which creates the symbolic link (if not existing).

Comment: AdobeMobileSDK is now also available in **cocoapods**!

http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AdobeMobileSDK/

Comment: "expecting the library to have a lib prefix" Oh my ... thank you !

Answer (score 4):

To be more generic for @fransen's solution, I used `prepare_command` and `preserve_paths`:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s| 
  s.name           = 'AdobeMobileLibrary'
  s.version        = '4.0.2'
  s.license        = 'Commercial'
  s.summary        = 'Adobe Omniture SiteCatalyst analytics library for iOS.'
  s.homepage       = 'https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/content_page/mobile/c-measuring-   mobile-applications'
  s.author         = { 'Adobe Omniture SiteCatalyst' => 'http://www.adobe.com/solutions/digital-marketing.html' }
  s.source_files   = 'AdobeMobileLibrary/*.h'
  s.resource       = 'AdobeMobileLibrary/ADBMobileConfig.json'
  s.framework      = 'SystemConfiguration'
  s.preserve_paths = 'AdobeMobileLibrary/libAdobeMobileLibrary.a'
  s.ios.vendored_library = 'AdobeMobileLibrary/AdobeMobileLibrary.a'
  s.prepare_command  = <<-CMD
             if [ -f $PWD/AdobeMobileLibrary/libAdobeMobileLibrary.a ]
             then
                 rm -rf $PWD/AdobeMobileLibrary/libAdobeMobileLibrary.a
             fi
             ln -s $PWD/AdobeMobileLibrary/AdobeMobileLibrary.a $PWD/AdobeMobileLibrary/libAdobeMobileLibrary.a
                          CMD
  s.libraries      = 'sqlite3.0'
  s.xcconfig       = { 'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"$(PODS_ROOT)/AdobeMobileLibrary"' }
end
```